# How to extend a RecyclerView in order to use it in a layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to extend a RecyclerView (i.e. inherit from RecyclerView Class), but when i try  to inherit from that class the app crash at run time). I searched on the web to understand how i can inherit from RecyclerView in order to avoid crash, but i can't find a complete example.
To be more specific the App crashes when is trying to inflate main_activity layout that holds the extended recyclerview. Any help?

Here is the code i have:

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

}
```

main_activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movies_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<-- Error here , app crash
     ....
end
```

Comment: I really can't understand this put on hold review... i provided anything is necessary to reproduce it... and indeed i got the right answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define a full path to your class, for example:

```
<my.package.MyRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/movies_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank You! I've tried to use the full class path in the imports, but i didn't in the xml layout. It works...

Comment: @S.Bozzoni you're welcome!